# Android studio directory in res directory not being included

Tags: android, gradle

I have added to my gradle script the following:

copy {
    def dirName='src/main/res/Resources'
    delete dirName
    from '../../Resources/'
    into dirName
    include '**'
}

This successfully copies the Resources directory and all subdirectories into the src/main/res/Resources directory, where directories such a s drawable, layout, mipmap-hdpi, and other preexisting included files are, but when I inspect the generated .apk file, there is no sign of my Resources directory or any of its subdirectories. How can I add this to the apk's res directory?

Comment: something about the delete keyword there?

Comment: And, why not using just the res?

Comment: I was using the delete so that it would clear the directory before copying it there. Could you clarify what you mean by using just the res? I tried sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs += '../../Resources'
    }, but that didn't put it there either, if that's what you mean.

Comment: No, i mean not using /Resources and using /res instead

Comment: The Resources directory is shared with a desktop version of the program, so I don't want to have to add files from somewhere in the android directory to the desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html

You can set your folder to be the resources folder, so it will be compiled into the APK instead of the res

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['resources/main']
        }
        debug {
            res.srcDirs = ['resources/debug']
        }
    }
}
```

You can also specify multiple resource directories for one source set, and then the build tools will merge them together. For example:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['res1', 'res2']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, but that didn't put it in the apk. What is that path relative to? I tried relative to res and the gradle file, it is still not adding it.

Comment: No, it do compile the folder as the res one and embedd it into the apk